# Linux Mint default physical screen before login

Tags: linux-mint, login, display-settings, mdm

I currently have to do annoying things to log into Linux Mint 16 Petra.
I have two screens:

```
new, left, VGA
old, right, DVI
```

The mouse is trapped on the left screen and the login dialogue for mdm is on the right screen. Changing the default screen/display inside the cinnamon environment does not solve this. I can't type in the password field, so I guess the keyboard input goes to the empty screen too.

Is there a way to choose the default display?

Comment: Apparently buying an HDMI cable fixes this. #wtf.